# spring.jackson.date-format='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' It doesn't work for LocalDateTime

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson, jackson-databind

Java8,spring-boot 2.7.15

```yaml
spring:
  jackson:
    date-format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
    property-naming-strategy: SNAKE_CASE
```

```java
@Data
public class User {
    private LocalDateTime createTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    private Date updateTime = new Date();
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("demo")
public class DemoController {

    @GetMapping(value = "user")
    public User demo1() {
        return new User();
    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxBhY.png)

I hope this setting to work globally like `java.util.Date` .
Thanks for your answer!